# How backwards compatible is php 5 with php 4?

Tags: php, backwards-compatibility, php4

I work on a code base written in php 4. I'd like to go through the process of upgrading the code to php 5 (the latest version my host provides). I'm wondering if anyone else has gone through a similar upgrade experience and can share what gotchas/pitfalls there are, what has to change in my code, what is not backwards compatible between the two versions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [guide for migrating from PHP 4 to 5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php). Your existing PHP 4 code should mostly still work, though there are some [backward-incompatible changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php).

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php) documentation page.
The most important section is [Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php).
AS long as you didn't use classes and objects in your previous application, array_merge is probably the only major problem you can encounter.

DO NOT enable the `zend.ze1_compatibility_mode` configuration variable.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the main source of pain is when the code relies on features that were already deprecated in PHP 4. Those are typically:

- [Register globals](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)
- [Magic quotes](http://es2.php.net/magic_quotes)
- Old fashioned session management, aka [session_register()](http://es.php.net/session_register)

There's no search and replace that can help you to identify such stuff. Removing it leads to tons of hard-to-spot failures. Keeping them leads to unmaintainable code. Setting an aggressive [error_reporting](http://es.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) level leads to an endless flood of notices.